# Lateral flatten into columns Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten

I have json like this

```
"sales_attributes":[
{
    "id":"100000",
    "name":"Colour",
    "value_id":"77777",
    "value_name":"Red Velvet"
},
{
    "id":"100089",
    "name":"Specification",
    "value_id":"88888",
    "value_name":"Bundle"
}]
```

and I want to make every attributes(name and value_name) become a column like this

| variant_field1 | variant_value1 | variant_field2 | variant_value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Colour | Red Velvet | Specification | Bundle |

I have tried with this query

```
SELECT 
sa.value:name::string as variant_field1,
sa.value:value_name::string as variant_value1,
FROM 
table,
LATERAN FLATTEN(input => sales_attributes) as sa
```

but the result like this

| variant_field1 | variant_value1 |
| --- | --- |
| Colour | Red Velvet |
| Specification | Bundle |

In this case I want the column created dynamically depend on count of dictionary

Thank you.

Comment: You will have to double parse the sql to dynamically build the set of columns. Generally in SQL unknown columns does not make a lot of sense. A standard answer is “the client will pull it apart” well in that case just return the JSON to the client to pull apart.

Comment: can you explain why you feel "dynamic columns" are the needed solution to your problem. One reason is "to have one block of code that works for all data" but this is a strange answer, given something has to have expectations of what it means to "have data" at which point the hyper-flexibility is not delivering value.